# Простите за каламбур

Tags: фразеология

Почему говорят: "**Простите** за каламбур"?

За что просят прощения?

Comment: Чтобы привлечь внимание к остроумию сказавшего, а то вдруг кто-то не заметил его прекрасный каламбур :)

Answer (score 3):

На самом деле просят прощения за тавтологию, а говорят почему-то "за каламбур". Путают понятия, скорей всего.

**Тавтология** (риторика) (от др.-греч. ταυτολογία) — риторическая фигура, представляющая собой повторение одних и тех же или близких по смыслу слов.

**Каламбур** представляет собой игру слов, одинаково произносимых, но разнозначащих (часто и разнопишущихся), так наз. «омонимов», или же основанную на соединении двух слов, однозвучных с каким-либо третьим словом. Соль К. заключается в разительном контрасте между смыслом одинаково звучащих слов.

Answer (score 3):

Видимо, за то, что о серьёзных вещах приходится говорить несерьёзно, случайно вышел каламбур,например:"Давайте поговорим о самой, простите за каламбур, болезненной теме – теме болезней и их лечения".

Answer (score 2):

Это ирония. Возможно потом стали употреблять серьезно, приняв за чистую монету.